# Javascript validation for user input (regExp)

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to wrap my head around RegExp. I currently have a form where I want to validate that the user input is only letters, (although an example of letter and number and spaces would be helpful to). I want this validation to be checked from a submit button. Can anyone help me out with my syntax/logic? Also please explain your answer so I can try to understand it. I'd also like to keep it in just JavaScript if possible, Any help in this matter would be greatly appreciated!

here is my form's code:

```
First name: <input type="text" name="firstName" /><br />
<span id="firstNameWarnings" style="color:black"> </span>

<button type="submit" onclick="return validateRegistrationForm()" >Register</button>
```

Note: My JavaScript runs all functions through master function. (submit calls the master function.)
here is my current JavaScript code:

```
        function validateFirstName()
        {
            var k=document.forms["registration"]["firstName"].value;
            var vld=new RegExp([A-Za-z]);

            if( k != vld)
            {
                document.getElementById("firstNameWarnings").style.color = "#F00";
                document.getElementById("firstNameWarnings").innerHTML = "First name onyl take letters!";
                return false;
            }
            else
            {
                document.getElementById("firstNameWarnings").innerHTML = "";
                return true;
            }
        }
```

Comment: Note that some people have a space or hyphen or apostrophe in their first name, e.g., Dac kien or Ann-Marie or La'tanya. Personally I think that (in English) the use of apostrophes like that is a ridiculous affectation on the part of the parents, but still the poor kids can't help it and they should be able to enter their preferred spelling with (apostrophe) into your system. (I assume you're already allowing hyphens and apostrophes in the family name fields, for names like Smythe-Hamilton and O'Conner?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the test method in RegExp

```
 if( vld.test(vk))
```

Here's more info on the RegExp test method.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test

Answer (score 0):

You can use this for check - `if (/^[a-zA-Z]+$/.test(k))`.

`^` - matches at the start of the string.

`[a-zA-Z]` - any character from range.

`+` - one or more times.

`$` - matches at the end of the string.